# how to update record using visual workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am new to visual workflow.I have added some new fields on an Object.I want to update these fields on existing records .Please provide me steps on how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SFSE.

This is a VERY broad subject, so there really is no one good solid answer.  You will have to be much more specific for help in certain areas once inside your new flow, but in a very small nutshell you can create a new flow by navigating to

**Setup -> Workflows & Approvals -> Flows -> New Flow**

I would really start here with the implementation guide.  this will give you all the necessary information to get you up and running using flows

http://na6.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf

Use this guide, set up a new flow, try to use the guide to build the flow around your requirements, then either update this question with more specifics, or ask a new question that is specific to an area within the flow in which you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Visual workflow has three DML Create, Update and Delete. You just need to drag and drop required operation from left side of visual workflow editior's data section. And make it  part of flow.

[image]

Drag record update block to the workspace and double click it to enter criteria and value according to which custom object will be updated.

Ex:

[image]

- Provided Name and Unique Name
- In Filter and Assignment Section by Update dropdown list select  Sobject to update
- Just below **select list** enter the criteria to match the record ( `id == {!Test1}`)
- After it select field to update and then select variable of which value selected field will be updated. `Access__c = {!Test2}`